# How do I prevent sitemap link from showing in Google search index?

Tags: php, magento, sitemap

I have moved my Magento files to the server `/` to root folder successfully, and I created and generated the google sitemap from **Admin Catalog > Google Sitemap**, and I added

```
Disallow: /magento/
```

to `robots.txt` file, but I still see `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml‎` shows when I do search in google by writing "site:www.example.com"

I tried also to remove robots.txt from root and I went to **System > Configuration > General > Design**, and at **Default Robots** I choose `INDEX, FOLLOW`

Still I see `www.example.com` appear in Google Search

I hope someone can guide me with a solution it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you have submitted your site index to Google Manually. Sign in to your account and delete your sitemap.